# displaying random q and their random ans

Tags: php, mysql

***i am making a quiz app using php and mysql and i have to display random questions..but i have defined static indexes for the answers..my program shows random question by refreshing the window but the answers index dont refresh according to question as they are static

```
       <?php 
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','test123');
mysql_select_db("quiz",$con);
?>
<html> 
<body> 
<form method="get" action="result.php">
<?php
$query="select m_question,a,b,c,d,e from mcq ORDER BY RAND()";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
$a=1;
for($j=0;$j<$rows;$j++)
{
echo "<br> $a." .mysql_result($result,$j,'m_question')."<br>" ;
echo "<input type = radio name=$a  value='a'>" .mysql_result($result,$j,'a');
echo "<input type = radio name=$a  value='b'>" .mysql_result($result,$j,'b');
echo "<input type = radio name=$a  value='c'>" .mysql_result($result,$j,'c');
echo "<input type = radio name=$a  value='d'>" .mysql_result($result,$j,'d');
echo "<input type = radio name=$a  value='e'>" .mysql_result($result,$j,'e');
$a++;
}
?>
<br>
<br>
<input type = "submit"  value ="submit result">
</body>
    </html>
```

and this is my result file where i am comparing results .ans of 1 questions is "b" option and and 2nd is "a" and so on...

```
 <?php 
    $result=0;
    if ($_GET[1]=='b')
    {$result++;}
    if ($_GET[2]=='a')
    {$result++;}
    if ($_GET[3]=='b')
    {$result++;}
    if ($_GET[4]=='b')
    {$result++;}
              echo "your score::".$result;
          ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'Static indexes for the answers', but you should remember that your database schema should always reflect the data stored in such a way that you could answer any questions you might have just by looking at the data available. Since I don't exactly know what you have based only on your code (you don't specify your schema, for example), I'll assume we're starting from scratch - and you can compare what you have to what I come up with.

### The Schema

First, you have two sets of data: Questions, and Answers. Since this is a quiz app, I'm presuming that the format of the quiz is 'Multiple Choice'; that is, each Question has two or more possible answers, and only one of them is correct.

This means that we should split the questions and the answers into two tables; lets call them '`questions`' and '`answers`' respectively.

#### Questions

In the '`questions`' table, we need a few things:

1. A unique, numeric identifier for each question. This is needed to set up any relationships in the future, so that we can point to any particular question easily (sure the text strings in the question are probably unique already, but when you want to quickly point to a specific item in the table, computers are much faster at comparing and searching through numbers than they are at comparing and searching through text). This will be our primary key.
2. The question itself. This is rather obvious.

So far, our schema looks something like this (primary keys in bold):

- questions

  - **q_id**
  - question

*Note: '`q_id`' (or whatever you name your primary key) should also be labeled as '`AUTO_INCREMENT`'. When you enter each question into the database, you leave that field 'null', and it'll automatically assign it the next available number.*

#### Answers

Now for the '`answers`' table, we'll need some different things. We'll need to identify each answer individually (to be able to point to each one they can choose), the question the answer belongs to, and we'll also have to be able to identify which one is the correct answer.

We can do this by having, along with an 'answer id' primary key, a 'foreign key' referencing the '`q_id`' column in the '`questions`' table, since it's the primary key for that table and thus identifies each row (each question) uniquely. Then all we need is the answer itself, and whether or not it's the correct answer. The end result is something like this:

- answers

  - **a_id**
  - q_id (foreign key: `questions.q_id`)
  - answer
  - correct (enum: 'yes', 'no')

This also allows for questions to have no right answer, or multiple right answers. You'd have to take care of your data to make sure it's in line with the quiz. If you want to restrict only one right answer per question, you can add a '`UNIQUE`' index that encompasses both '`q_id`' and '`correct`'. In MySQL, it'd look something like:

```
UNIQUE INDEX (q_id, correct),
```

That would go inside of your CREATE TABLE statement, or into a separate ALTER TABLE statement.

*Note: '`q_id`' in '`answers`' should* not *use either AUTO_INCREMENT* or *be a primary key. If you feel it is causing a bottleneck, put an index on it.*

#### Example Data Set

To help see this schema in action, lets make a simple quiz:

- questions

  - 1, "How many inches are in a mile?";
  - 2, "Why do people breathe air?";
  - 3, "Why is Monty Python popular?";
- answers

  - 1, 1, "63,360", 'yes';
  - 2, 1, "5,280", 'no';
  - 3, 1, "Over a million", 'no';
  - 4, 1, "Several Hundred", 'no';
  - 5, 2, "So they don't die", 'yes';
  - 6, 2, "Because it's cool", 'no';
  - 7, 2, "Because it's polite", 'no';
  - 8, 2, "So they can laugh at people who don't", 'no';
  - 9, 3, "Because people find it funny", 'yes';
  - 10, 3, "Because it is", 'no';
  - 11, 3, "Because of the French", 'no';
  - 12, 3, "It's popular?", 'no';

### Querying in PHP

There are two sets of queries to worry about here: grabbing the questions, and grabbing the answers. I would like to first point out that in your code examples, you're using the old, antiquated 'mysql' set of functions ('`mysql_query`', '`mysql_result`', and so forth).

This is HIGHLY discouraged, and you should learn to use either the newer ['Mysqli'](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) library, or the more abstracted ['PDO'](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) library. I will be using Mysqli.

#### Method 1: All at once.

The first way you could run the queries, is to select *all* the questions, and then *all* the answers at once, put them into a data structure (your own class, or just a nested array), and then randomize the order in which they're displayed. Here is some code showing this. The comments are worth reading:

```
<?php

//Connect to MySQL:
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "tynach", "505.2.0", "quiz");

//Grab the question list:
$get_questions = $con->prepare("SELECT q_id, question FROM questions");
$get_questions->execute();
$get_questions->bind_result($q_id, $question);

$questions = array();

while ($get_questions->fetch()) {
    // We use $q_id twice because if you scramble the array, the first one
    // changes. However, we still might want to keep track of the original
    // question ID number.

    // The reason we use it in that first spot to begin with is so that we
    // know for sure that we can associate the answers to the correct
    // questions.
    $questions[$q_id] = array($q_id, $question, array());
}

// Grab the answer list:
$get_answers = $con->prepare("SELECT a_id, q_id, answer, correct FROM answers");
$get_answers->execute();
$get_answers->bind_result($a_id, $q_id, $answer, $correct);

while ($get_answers->fetch()) {
    $questions[$q_id][2][$a_id] = array($a_id, $answer, $correct);
}

// Scramble the array, and print it out:
shuffle($questions);
var_dump($questions);

?>
```

The output to that is:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    string(30) "How many inches are in a mile?"
    [2]=>
    array(4) {
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        int(1)
        [1]=>
        string(6) "63,360"
        [2]=>
        string(3) "yes"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        int(2)
        [1]=>
        string(5) "5,280"
        [2]=>
        string(2) "no"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        int(3)
        [1]=>
        string(14) "Over a million"
        [2]=>
        string(2) "no"
      }
      [4]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        int(4)
        [1]=>
        string(15) "Several Hundred"
        [2]=>
        string(2) "no"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
    [1]=>
    string(26) "Why do people breathe air?"
    [2]=>
    array(4) {
      [5]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        int(5)
        [1]=>
        string(17) "So they don't die"
        [2]=>
        string(3) "yes"
      }
      [6]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        int(6)
        [1]=>
        string(17) "Because it's cool"
        [2]=>
        string(2) "no"
      }
      [7]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        int(7)
        [1]=>
        string(19) "Because it's polite"
        [2]=>
        string(2) "no"
      }
      [8]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        int(8)
        [1]=>
        string(37) "So they can laugh at people who don't"
        [2]=>
        string(2) "no"
      }
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(3)
    [1]=>
    string(28) "Why is Monty Python popular?"
    [2]=>
    array(4) {
      [9]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        int(9)
        [1]=>
        string(28) "Because people find it funny"
        [2]=>
        string(3) "yes"
      }
      [10]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        int(10)
        [1]=>
        string(13) "Because it is"
        [2]=>
        string(2) "no"
      }
      [11]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        int(11)
        [1]=>
        string(21) "Because of the French"
        [2]=>
        string(2) "no"
      }
      [12]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        int(12)
        [1]=>
        string(13) "It's popular?"
        [2]=>
        string(2) "no"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I had more to write, but I'm about to go to a Superbowl party, so I'll edit this post with more info later.